# P-values from Different Distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I was just considering the following hypothetical scenario, where suppose we have $X_1,...,X_n$ observations, and for each observation, we then assume that each are associated respectively with the following null distributions $H_1:N(\mu_1,\sigma_1),...,H_n:N(\mu_n,\sigma_n)$, where $\mu_1\neq...\neq\mu_n$ and $\sigma_1\neq ... \neq \sigma_n$.

I would like to declare $X_i$ as significant if it is larger than their mean ($\mu_i$) with a p-value < 0.05 under their null ($H_i$). Normally, I would just compute p-values from $H_0:N(\mu_0,\sigma_0)$, but here I do it with respect to each null. For each $X_i$, I compute a 1 sided p-value: $P(X_i\geq \mu_i|H_i)$.

I would be performing multiple hypothesis tests, so can I subject those p-values to a FDR control procedure, say Benjamini-Hochberg? My concern is that the p-values are not computed under the same null, but that might not be an issue.

This problem doesn't quite seem like a meta-analysis problem, but it also doesn't seem like a standard multiple hypothesis correction problem.

Perhaps this problem is well studied, and I am unable to correctly phrase this problem, but I haven't been able to resolve this question. Thanks in advance.

Edit: More generally, if each of the assumed null distributions was somewhat arbitrary, taking some distributional form specified by $D_i(P_i)$, where $P_i$ is the set of parameters describing $D_i$, would statements made about the above still hold true for arbitrary distributions $D_i$, if we have finite means and variances? $D_i$ could be a Gumbel, Gamma, or a Beta.

Comment: I can't make sense of this post, because it looks self-contradictory.  Which, exactly, are the null hypotheses?  Are they the $H_0$ you write in the second paragraph or are they the "null distributions" of the first paragraph?  And could you explain what you mean by "most significant"?  (Would that mean those with lowest p-value?  If so, *what are the alternative hypotheses??*)  Could you clarify?

Comment: After the edits I *think* I understand the question.  It seems to me it could be rephrased in terms of the standardized variables $Z_i=(X_i-\mu_i)/\sigma_i,$ because you seem to take all the parameters as specified.  If so, then the issue of not the "same null" disappears, because now all of them are $H_i:Z_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1).$  Would this reflect the interpretation you intended?  If so, are there any obstacles that remain?

Comment: Just to make sure, you want to run tests where you have a single observation for each test? These tests will have a quite bad power of course. Apart from that there's no particular problem that'd make standard approaches such as Benjamini-Hochberg (B-H) invalid. B-H for sure doesn't require that all the null hypotheses are the same.

Comment: @whuber Yes, that accurately reflects my intention, so there aren't any obstacles. That was a helpful way to reframe the question. Based on Lewian's comment, there wouldn't be anything inappropriate about running the BH procedure directly on the obtained p-values either. Would that make any difference?

Comment: @Lewian Thanks for pointing that out. My original question intended for it to be a single observation, but on second thought, I don't think the scenario changes much if I had multiple observations for each group, and used the mean of that group. So instead of $X_i$, it'd just be $\bar{X_i}$.